# Using Simple Scheduler Gem for Scheduling Tasks in a Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I am trying to run a method that adds the response from an API call to Cache, I decided to use the [simple_scheduler gem](https://github.com/simplymadeapps/simple_scheduler)

Below are snippets of code that I am running

```
#  update_cache_job.rb

class UpdateCacheJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def perform
    return QueuedJobs.new.update_cache
  end
end
```

And

```
# simple_scheduler.yml

# Global configuration options. The `queue_ahead` and `tz` options can also be set on each task.
queue_ahead: 120 # Number of minutes to queue jobs into the future
queue_name: "default" # The Sidekiq queue name used by SimpleScheduler::FutureJob
tz: "nil" # The application time zone will be used by default if not set

# Runs once every 2 minutes
simple_task:
  class: "UpdateCacheJob"
  every: "2.minutes"
```

And the method I have scheduled to run every 2.minutes

```
class QueuedJobs
  include VariableHelper
    def initialize; end

    def update_cache
      @variables = obtain_software_development_table
       #   First refresh the project Reviews

       puts 'Updating reviews...'

       @records = Dashboard.new.obtain_projects_reviews.pluck(
       obtain_project_reviews_student_variable,
       obtain_project_reviews_id_variable,
     'Project'
           ).map { |student, id, project| { 'Student': student, 'ID': id,   
     'Project': project } }
       Rails.cache.write(
       :reviews,
       @records,
       expires_in: 15.minutes
       )
       @grouped_reviews = Rails.cache.read(
       :reviews
       ).group_by do |review|
       review[:Student]&.first
     end

     puts 'reviews refreshed.'

    #   Then refresh the coding challenges submissions

    puts "Updating challenges submissions.."
    @all_required_submissions_columns = Dashboard.new.all_coding_challenges_submissions.all.map do |submission|
      {
        id: submission.id,
        'Student': submission[obtain_coding_chall_subm_student_var],
        'Challenge': submission[obtain_coding_chall_subm_challenge_var]
      }
    end
    @all_grouped_submissions = @all_required_submissions_columns.group_by { |challenge| challenge[:Student]&.first }
    Rails.cache.write(
      :challenges_submissions,
      @all_grouped_submissions,
      expires_in: 15.minutes
    )

    puts "challenges submissions refreshed."
    end
end
```

I have been able to reach these methods from the rails console but when ever I run `rake simple_scheduler` It just logs the first puts and sometimes it does nothing at all.

What do I need to do here?

Comment: Small remark: the indentation makes your code unreadable. You should fix that. More to the point: the `rake simple_scheduler` just schedules the recurring jobs, you still need a backend to actually run the jobs, not sure if that was clear.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it is not clear what you are saying

Comment: Rails activejob is an interface, but you still need to configure a backend that actually runs the jobs (e.q. que, delayedjob, sidekiq, ...). I am not sure if that was clear for you? You seem to expect the `rake simple_scheduler` should run the jobs, but it will only _schedule_ recurring jobs.

Comment: It's clear now, I am currently looking at :sidekiq gem. Thank you

Comment: @nathanvdaIt works now, I removed simple_scheduler gem and went with redis, sidekiq and sidekiq-cron, worked like a charm.

Comment: Super!! You should answer your own question 